# Search and kill process, and start new process on bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, kill

I need a script for running a new process every hour.

I created a bash script that is scheduled to run every hour through cron. It only works the first time but fails otherwise.

If run from shell, it works perfectly.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

ps -ef | grep tcpdump | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
sleep 2
echo "Lanzando tcpdump"
tcpdump -ni eth0 -s0 proto TCP and port 25  -w /root/srv108-$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).smtp.pcap
```

cron

```
@hourly /root/analisis.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Why is the cron job failing?

Comment: That's not a Bash script (the shebang says otherwise).

Comment: [How does it fail?](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/) And can't you use `killall`, or at least `pidof`?

Comment: @abkrim, Use `pkill -f tcpdump` to kill a process.

Comment: To try and debug it yourself, change the cron line to log stdout and stderr to a file and run set -x or add -x to the first line to turn on debugging.  Cron doesn't have your same environment as regular shell commands so you may just be missing commands from the path. Try giving full paths to the commands in the kill line.

Comment: Oh and when debugging, copy the kill line and just look at the output of each step. It may be that ps has a different output format depending on the environment.  Set the command to run every minute in cron and you can debug quickly.

Comment: This may sound redundant, but try redirecting the `tcpdump` to `/dev/null` if you don't need the output. That did it for me on a similar case.

Comment: Well. Change shebang to bash @Biffen. Also change `pkill -f tcpdump` to kill a process, @sat Now try debug, after fail two tries.

Comment: Thks @MikeWodarczyk When debug I see problem. On crontab enviroment I need put full path for tcpdump, because script on cron not found binary.

Comment: Please do not add "solved" in the title. Instead, post an answer with the solution: [Can I answer my own question?](/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>This is the answer the OP [added](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42241586/revisions) to the question itself.</sub>

**Correction of the script after the comments (it works fine)**

```
#!/bin/bash

pkill -f tcpdump
/usr/sbin/tcpdump -ni eth0 -s0 proto TCP and port 25  -w /root/srv108-$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).smtp.pcap
```

That is, I just needed to use the full path to `tcpdump`.

Answer (score 0):

The failure may be related to the cron job never finishing - you are starting a new tcpdump in the foreground, which will run forever.

Try this simplified script:

```
#!/bin/bash
killall tcpdump
tcpdump -ni eth0 -s0 proto TCP and port 25  -w /root/srv108-$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).smtp.pcap&
```

Comment: Be quickly answer. Real not problem what you say. With debug I see problem. `/root/analisis.sh: línea 7: tcpdump: no roder found`.

Comment: @abkrim if the missing path is the problem, how come it works the first time?

Comment: **enviroment**. Awnser to your question are on older comments, not equal bash enviroment of user, that cron, on this system @SirAthos